# Simultaneous TCP termination and subsequent connect(): EADDRNOTAVAIL

Tags: linux, sockets, networking, tcp

My company releases a special TCP stack for special purposes and I'm tasked with implementing RFC793 compliant closing sequence. One of the unit tests has a server working on top of the special TCP stack talking to a normal Linux TCP client, and I'm running into some strange behaviour that I'm not sure whether is caused by programming error on my part or is to be expected.

Before my work started, we used to send a RST packet when the user application calls close(). I've implemented the FIN handshake, but I noticed that in the case of simultaneous TCP termination (FIN_WAIT_1 -> CLOSING -> TIME_WAIT on both ends, see the picture), the standard Linux TCP client cannot connect to the same destination address and port again, with connect() returning with EADDRNOTAVAIL, until after TIME_WAIT passes into CLOSED.

[image: simultaneous close]

Now, the standard Linux client application sets the option **SO_REUSEADDR**, binds the socket to port 8888 each time, and connects to destination port 6666. My question is, why does bind() succeed and why does connect() fail? I would have thought SO_REUSEADDR could take over a local TIME_WAIT port, which it did, but what does connect() have against talking to the destination-ip:6666 again?

Is my code doing something it shouldn't or is this expected behaviour?

I can confirm no SYN packet for the failed connect() makes it out of the client machine at all. I've attached a screenshot of the FIN handshake for the above session.

[image]

Comment: 'The standard Linux client application sets the option SO_REUSEADDR, binds the socket to port 8888 each time.' Why? What do you care what the local outbound port is?

Comment: @EJP
I didn't write the unit test, I wanted to make sure my change didn't break anything.

The mainline version of the software sends a reset, you see, so by the time the second test comes around the port is already closed, so this doesn't happen. I am curious whether what I observe is expected.

Is there something from your experience that suggests one way or another?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your previous implementation used `RST` to end the connection. Receipt of an `RST` packet immediately removes the connection from the active connection table. That's because there is no further possibility of receiving a valid packet on that connection: the peer has just told your system that that session is not valid.

If you do a proper session termination with `FIN`, on the other hand, there is the last packet problem: how do you know for sure whether the peer actually received the last acknowledgment you sent to *their* `FIN` (this is the definition of TCP's `TIME_WAIT` state)? And if the peer didn't receive it, they might validly send another copy of the `FIN` packet which your machine should then re-`ACK`.

Now, your `bind` succeeds because you're using `SO_REUSEADDR`, but you still cannot create a new connection with the *exact same ports on both sides* because that entry is still in your active connection table (in `TIME_WAIT` state). The 4-tuple (IP1, port1, IP2, port2) must always be unique.

As @EJP suggested in the comment, it is unusual for the client to specify a port, and there is typically no reason to. I would change your test.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it's very reassuring. Do you know why it might be the case that the above error only happens when both ends are in TIME_WAIT? I can confirm this only occurs in simultaneous termination when both go to TIME_WAIT, and not in any other cases.

Is what might be the reason for this design choice in Linux?

Comment: Hmm... I would expect this to happen on the "active close" side every time (that is, the side that sent the first `FIN`) -- or both sides for a simultaneous close. Is it possible your software might not be treating the `TIME_WAIT` exactly right? That is, it technically shouldn't accept a new connection request to port 6666 from port 8888 on the client IP if there's already a connection entry for that pair of ports in `TIME_WAIT` state but if you did anyway, and simply overwrote the entry, that would rarely cause a visible problem.

Comment: Also, as you saw, when the *client* side is in `TIME_WAIT` state, your `SYN` packet  is never leaving the box, so it won't matter what the server side's state is.

Comment: Finally, this behavior is part of the TCP specification so not really a linux "design choice".

Comment: I ran the same client and server applications, this time both on top of Linux's standard TCP/IP stack. I can confirm when the client performs an active close (I added a sleep() before the close() function in the server code for now and verified tcpdump captures as well), this error doesn't happen.

Comment: I'm looking at the code in inet_hashtable.c. Does Linux treat connections where both ends are in TIME_WAIT differently than when only one end is in TIME_WAIT, maybe?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/176378/discussion-between-user3109672-and-gil-hamilton).